# Unable to configure TLS options for OpenLDAP

Tags: openldap

I am struggling with setting up TLS for a new OpenLDAP server. The system is Debian Jessie (updated to the latest 8.7 stable), and I have set up the server by installing the `slapd` package, with almost no modifications to date.

One of the things I am trying to configure is the TLS Cipher Suite. Here is the LDIF:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCipherSuite
olcTLSCipherSuite: HIGH
```

When I try to submit this change with the following command:

```
ldapmodify -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f set-cipher-suite.ldif
```

I get this error:

```
ldap_modify: Server is unwilling to perform (53)
```

I also tried to set the certificate file with the following LDIF:

```
dn: cn=config
changetype: modify
add: olcTLSCertificateFile
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/foo.crt
```

Here I get an error 80 instead of an error 53.

```
ldap_modify: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
```

I double-checked that the file exists and that `slapd` has access to the file.

I changed `olcLogLevel` to `any` (thus proving that I am capable of modifying the configuration) and checked the debug output, but what I see there has no information value to my untrained eye. Here is the snippet where error 53 occurs:

```
[...]
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: slap_queue_csn: queueing 0x7f3648f4a430 20160608144621.742848Z#000000#000#000000
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: oc_check_required entry (cn=config), objectClass "olcGlobal"
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: oc_check_allowed type "objectClass"
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: oc_check_allowed type "cn"
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: oc_check_allowed type "olcArgsFile"
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: oc_check_allowed type "olcLogLevel"
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: oc_check_allowed type "olcPasswordHash"
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: oc_check_allowed type "olcPidFile"
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: oc_check_allowed type "olcToolThreads"
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: oc_check_allowed type "structuralObjectClass"
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: oc_check_allowed type "entryUUID"
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: oc_check_allowed type "creatorsName"
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: oc_check_allowed type "createTimestamp"
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: oc_check_allowed type "olcTLSCipherSuite"
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: oc_check_allowed type "entryCSN"
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: oc_check_allowed type "modifiersName"
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: oc_check_allowed type "modifyTimestamp"
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: send_ldap_result: conn=1002 op=1 p=3
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: send_ldap_result: err=53 matched="" text=""
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: send_ldap_response: msgid=2 tag=103 err=53
Jun  8 16:46:21 pelargir slapd[36937]: conn=1002 op=1 RESULT tag=103 err=53 text=
[...]
```

Can anyone give me a hint what I might be doing wrong here? What I find utterly baffling is that I can successfully modify simple options such as `olcLogLevel` or `olcPasswordHash`, but that I fail when I try to do the same for similarly simple TLS options such as `olcTLSCipherSuite`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue with

```
olcTLSCipherSuite: HIGH
```

is that GnuTLS does not know the "HIGH" cipher suite, because this is a convenience name supported only by OpenSSL. If you want to see the available cipher names supported by GnuTLS, run the command `gnutls-cli -l`. Install the `gnutls-bin` Debian package to get access to the `gnutls-cli` utility.

The issue with

```
olcTLSCertificateFile: /etc/ssl/certs/foo.crt
```

I could not reproduce after more than 3 years. As Alexander Kjäll pointed out in his answer, it could have been a permission problem after all.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem, openldap in debian is compiled against the gnu-tls package and that is not installed by default.

This might help:

```
apt install gnutls-bin
```

Also make sure that the openldap user have sufficient permissions to read the certificates. For example:

```
useradd letsencrypt
chown openldap:letsencrypt /etc/letsencrypt/ -R
usermod -a -G letsencrypt openldap
```

Comment: It's true that OpenLDAP in Debian is compiled against GnuTLS, but that is covered by the `slapd` package depending on a GnuTLS _library_ package (currently `libgnutls-deb0-28`). The package you are suggesting (`gnutls-bin`) contains commandline utilities, which is certainly not something the OpenLDAP server is going to need. I tried installing `gnutls-bin` on the off chance that I might be wrong, but as expected this didn't help. Regarding file permissions: As mentioned in the question that's something I already checked.